# Is there a tool that is similar to the ArcGIS repair geometry tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need a tool in QGIS that has the same functionality as the [repair geometry tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000) (native of ArcGIS).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqJbVh_OqCE using http://postgis.org/docs/ST_MakeValid.html and also https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/bad-bad-polygon-fixing-invalid-geometries-with-quantum-gis/ that's all that google turned up in less than a minute.

Comment: Also from GRASS, to add what @MichaelMiles-Stimson has included in his last link, you can use the **v.clean** toolset for cleaning the topology of vector maps.